# How to send a pipe with psexec?

Tags: windows-server-2003, pstools

I'm trying to execute a pipe on a remote server by using `psexec`.

The command that I'm trying to execute is

```
psexec \\servername DSQUERY USER -name *userpart* | DSGET USER -samid -display
```

Currently, the | pipe symbol get executed locally which is not what is wanted (since `dsget` does not exist on my machine).

I tried to use quote around the whole command

```
psexec \\servername "DSQUERY USER -name *userpart* | DSGET USER -samid -display"
```

but that resulted in psexec trying to run that whole quoted sentence as one executable, which obviously does not exist.

How can I pass a pipe symbol to the remote server so that it can execute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible suggestions come to mind: try to escape the pipe character with a caret (ie. ^|) if that doesn't work, you can create a batch file on the remote machine (including the piped command) and execute the batch file using psexec.

Comment: Using a pipe did not work with the error that DSGET is not an argument of DSQUERY. Of course creating a batch file will work, but I feel unsatisfied. Though I give you +1 for telling me how to escape a character in the command prompt.